# Change and Add value into array then show it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.inp').click(function(){
  var arr = [];
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(value == 'empty') {
    $(this).val(id+'ON');
    arr.push(value);
  }
  if(value == id+'ON') {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1);
    $(this).val(id+'OFF');
    arr.push(value);
  }
  if(value == id+'OFF') {
    $(this).val('empty');
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1);
  }
  $('.txt').val(arr.join(','));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class='txt' type='input'>
  <input class='inp' id='x' type='button' value='empty'>
  <input class='inp' id='y' type='button' value='empty'>
  <input class='inp' id='z' type='button' value='empty'>
</form>
```

In my script here, I'm trying to make the `.txt` to obtain the values `ON, OFF` only, But in the part

```
if(value == 'empty') {
    $(this).val(id+'ON');
    arr.push(value);
  }
```

the `.txt` pushes `empty` instead of the new value `id+ON`

Also when i click on another button, the entire `.txt` is removed and adds the clicked button value only,

For example if i clicked `#x` the `.txt` should be `xON`, And if i clicked `#y` while `.txt` has the value `xON`

i want it to be `xON,yON` but it becomes `yON` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every button click, `var arr = [];`, This statement is creating an empty array for you. This should be populated from existing text field.

Comment: I see, the scope placement was wrong. that solved the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

Cause you're using this:

```
var value = $(this).val();//the value of the pressed button is always "empty"
```

Instead of this:

```
var value = id+'ON';
```

or:

```
arr.push(id+'ON');
```

You're saying that your `var value` contains `"empty"` so the `array` will push the value `empty`.

Comment: in the part `if(value == 'empty') {
    $(this).val(id+'ON');
    arr.push(value);
  }` What i understand from it logically that if the value is `empty` which is the default, then change this clicked button value into `id+'ON'` then after changing it push this new value into the array, Why would it push the original vlaue?

Comment: @AXAI the value of the variable `value` will remain the same even after you change the input's value.

Comment: @AXAI if you want to get the new value then you should get it again before pushing it using this instruction `value = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear from the question wording what the full requirements are, but I think this may be what you're looking for.

```js
$(function() {
  var list = {};

  $('.inp').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var newVal = id;

    if (value == 'empty') {
      newVal += 'ON';
      $(this).val(newVal);
      list[id] = newVal;
    }
    if (value == id + 'ON') {
      newVal += 'OFF';
      $(this).val(id + 'OFF');
      list[id] = newVal;
    } else if (value == id + 'OFF') {
      $(this).val('empty');
      list[id] = null;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
    var output = "";
    for (key in list) {
      if (list[key] != null) {
        if (output != "") output += ",";
        output += list[key];
      }
    }
    $('.txt').val(output);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class='txt' type='input'>
  <input class='inp' id='x' type='button' value='empty'>
  <input class='inp' id='y' type='button' value='empty'>
  <input class='inp' id='z' type='button' value='empty'>
</form>
```

If this isn't quite what you meant, then please clarify what exactly is needed.

Comment: The final result is exactly what i want.

Comment: @AXAI great. If it has helped you please remember to mark the answer as accepted - thanks :-)

Comment: Is it possible to refactor it to use arrays instead of objects? since i'm not very perfect at using object.

Comment: it's actually easier with an object because you can make an association with the ID of the button, and then use that to remove the item again later. With an array that's not so easy, since it requires you to use numeric indexes. And if you aren't confident with objects, you can use the code above as an opportunity to learn - it's a very useful skill and not so hard once you get used to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var values = {};

  $('.inp').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
      value = $(this).val(),
      newVal = id,
      finalVal = '';
    if (value == 'empty') {
      newVal += 'ON';
      values[id] = '';
    } else {
      if (value == (id + 'ON'))
        newVal += 'OFF';
      else
        newVal = 'empty';
      values[id] = value;
    }
    $(this).val(newVal);
    for (key in values) {
      if (values.hasOwnProperty(key) && !!values[key]) {
        finalVal += values[key];
      }
    }
    $('.txt').val(finalVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class='txt' type='input'>
  <input class='inp' id='x' type='button' value='xON'>
  <input class='inp' id='y' type='button' value='yON'>
  <input class='inp' id='z' type='button' value='zON'>
</form>
```

Comment: the `.txt` is supposed to have the same value the input has, so for `xON` value the `.txt` should have `xON` in it too, But for the multiple value part, yes, that perfect.

Comment: hmm.. i just answered what supposed to make sense. when you click the button, the field will be updated with the value. so when clicking `xON`, the field will be updated with `xON`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get empty instead of `id+'ON'` is because the variable `value` contains the string 'empty', a primitive hence assigned by value. In javascript assignment by value, as opposed to assignment by reference, implies the value in the variable can not change unless reassigned. To get the new value you should call `value = $(this).val();` before `arr.push(value);` so that you push the updated `value`.

Because you have declared `arr` inside the click handler, every time a button is clicked, the array is reinitialized. To get the desired result, move the declaration `var arr = [];` outside the callback function.

Also, you should not call `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1);` inside the block `if(value == id+'ON')` because that will remove it from `arr`. and your history will be inconsistent. If you do not want the values `empty` appearing in `.txt` input. remove `arr.push(value);` from the block `if(value == 'empty')`

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/kharhys/pen/QqMPBx) with the described edits.